# Nginx - Daphne deployment issue

Tags: nginx, daphne

I recently added a function utilizing WebSocket with Channels to Django web application and having some trouble. Since the Channels and WebSocket work just fine with the local test server (`manage.py runserver`), one can tell that the deployment part is responsible.

Here are some setting files and status checks:

nginx_conf.conf

```
#added this block
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:9001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY_URL;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/MY_USER/server/mysite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/server/mysite/mysite.sock;
    }

    #path to proxy my WebSocket requests
    location /ws/ {

 #       proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/server/mysite/mysite_w.sock;
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

daphne.service

```
[Unit]
Description=daphne daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
User=MY_USER
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/MY_USER/server/mysite
#ExecStart=/home/MY_USER/server/server/bin/daphne -u /home/MY_USER/server/mysite/mysite_w.sock  mysite.asgi:application -v2
ExecStart=/home/MY_USER/server/server/bin/daphne -p 9001 mysite.asgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As you can see I've tested both port and UNIX socket for binding and both are not successful.

1. PORT case
   Chrome console message

```
(index):16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://MY_URL/ws/chat/test/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
(anonymous) @ (index):16
(index):30 Chat socket closed unexpectedly
chatSocket.onclose @ (index):30
2(index):43 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

`❯ sudo less /var/log/nginx/access.log`

```
61.82.112.1 - - [12/Aug/2020:06:27:29 +0000] "GET /chat/test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 682 "http://MY_URL/chat/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
61.82.112.1 - - [12/Aug/2020:06:27:30 +0000] "GET /ws/chat/test/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
```

`❯ sudo journalctl -u mysite-daphne.service`

```
Aug 10 09:31:32 hermes systemd[1]: mysite-daphne.service: Succeeded.
Aug 10 09:31:32 hermes systemd[1]: Stopped daphne daemon.
Aug 10 09:31:32 hermes systemd[1]: Started daphne daemon.
```

Which looks like Daphne did not get the message from Nginx.

2. UNIX socket case
   Chrome console message

```
(index):16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://MY_URL/ws/chat/test/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
(anonymous) @ (index):16
(index):30 Chat socket closed unexpectedly
chatSocket.onclose @ (index):30
3(index):43 WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
document.querySelector.onclick @ (index):43
document.querySelector.onkeyup @ (index):36
```

`❯ sudo less /var/log/nginx/access.log`

```
61.82.112.1 - - [12/Aug/2020:06:42:44 +0000] "GET /ws/chat/test/ HTTP/1.1" 400 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

`❯ sudo journalctl -u mysite-daphne.service`

```
Aug 10 09:31:32 hermes systemd[1]: Stopped daphne daemon.
Aug 10 09:31:32 hermes systemd[1]: Started daphne daemon.
```

I need some advice for troubleshooting. Please feel free to ask any extra info which may be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem and was starting to go mad.

Your nginx config contains the same wrong statement as mine did:

```
[...]
proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
[...]
```

The word *upgrade* is enclosed by the wrong quotes. You need to have standard quotes here (ASCII code 34, Shift-2 on the keyboard), not the "fancy" unicode quotes. Very very hard to find.

Some websites seem to convert standard quotes to unicode shifted quotes because someone thinks they look better...

Comment: Thank you, Markus. Your solution was the answer!!